# cgo pcre return "PCRE_ERROR_MATCHLIMIT" (-8)

Tags: go, pcre, cgo

I just trying to make a pcre matching function by using cgo, but I received -8 from C.pcre_exec which means "PCRE_ERROR_MATCHLIMIT". when I run only c code, that returns -1. I think the result from the c code is right. how can I solve that?
This is my C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pcre.h>

void println(const char *s) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
}


pcre* comp(const char* regex) {

    const char* error;
    int error_offset;

    pcre* re = pcre_compile(regex, PCRE_CASELESS, &error, &error_offset, NULL);
    if (re == NULL) {
        return NULL;  // error compiling regex
    }

    return re;

}

int pexec(pcre* re, char *buf, int len, int options, int *ov, int ovlen, int flags) {

    int ret;

    ret = pcre_exec(re, NULL, buf, len, flags, options, ov, ovlen);

    return ret;
}

int main(){

    pcre* re;

    char* string;
    char *pattern="{{(?:\\n|\\r\\n?|.)*?[^\\w\\d\\s\\-,:_]+(?:\\n|\\r\\n?|.)*?}}";

    re=comp(pattern);


    const char **error;

    FILE *ptr_file;
    int len;

    int i;
    char buf[1000];

    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    ptr_file = fopen("/root/go/src/bwlc/tdata", "r");
    if (NULL == ptr_file) {
        printf("ptr_file is null\n");
        return -1;
    }

    len = fread(buf, 1, 1000, ptr_file);
    fclose(ptr_file);

    int ret;
    int ovector_qp[3]={0,};
  
    Struct result;
    int ovlen=sizeof(ovector_qp) / sizeof(int);

    result=pexec(re, buf, len, 0, ovector_qp, ovlen, 0);

    printf("Result : %d\n", result.res);


    return 0;
}
```

and this is my data

```
"{,~{,{{\r\n- follow_1: \r\n[\r\n\t[\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"match_type\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\"from\": -1,\r\n\t\t\t\"distance\": 100,\r\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"(\\\\$|#|\\\\*|\\\\{)?\\\\{\\ *(['\\\"\\\\d]+\\ *[\\\\+\\\\-*\\\\/%]\\ *['\\\"\\\\d]+)\\ *\\\\}\\\\}?\"\r\n\t\t}\r\n\t]\r\n]</code></pre>\r\n<ul id=\"bkmrk-regex101\">\r\n<li class=\"null\"><strong>regex"
```

That's the result

```
Result : -1
```

This is my Go code

```
package main
/*

#cgo LDFLAGS: -lpcre
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/opt/local/include

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pcre.h>


void println(const char *s) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

struct data
{
    int res;
    int sIndex;
    int lIndex;
};

typedef struct data Struct;

pcre* comp(const char* regex) {
    const char* error;
    int error_offset;

    pcre* re = pcre_compile(regex, PCRE_CASELESS, &error, &error_offset, NULL);
    if (re == NULL) {
        return NULL;  // error compiling regex
    }
    return re;
}

Struct pexec(pcre* re, char *buf, int len, int options, int *ov, int ovlen) {

    int ret;
    int ovplen;
    Struct r;

    ret = pcre_exec(re, NULL, buf, len, 0, options, ov, ovlen);
    r.res = ret;

    if (ret >= 0) {
        r.sIndex = ov[0];
        r.lIndex = ov[1];
    }

    return r;
}


*/
import (
    "C"
)
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    ErrNullbyte   error = errors.New("NULL BYTE IN PATTERN")
    ErrNotmatch   error = errors.New("NOT MATCHED")
    ErrInvFlag    error = errors.New("INVALID OPTION FLAG")
    ErrBadoption  error = errors.New("BAD OPTION")
    ErrMatchLimit error = errors.New("ERROR_MATCHLIMIT")
    ErrNotInit    error = errors.New("NOT INITIALIZED")
)

type Pcre struct {
    Regex []byte
}

func OCompile(pattern string, flags int) (*Pcre, error) {
    patternC := C.CString(pattern)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(patternC))

    if clen := int(C.strlen(patternC)); clen != len(pattern) {
        return nil, ErrNullbyte
    }

    var err *C.char
    var erroffset C.int

    regex := C.pcre_compile(patternC, C.int(flags), &err, &erroffset, nil)
    if regex == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Error : " + C.GoString(err) + ", Offset : " + strconv.Itoa(int(erroffset)))
    }

    size := pcreSize(regex)

    pcres := Pcre{
        Regex: make([]byte, size),
    }
    C.memcpy(unsafe.Pointer(&pcres.Regex[0]), unsafe.Pointer(regex), size)

    return &pcres, nil
}

func pcreSize(regex *C.pcre) (size C.size_t) {
    C.pcre_fullinfo(regex, nil, C.PCRE_INFO_SIZE, unsafe.Pointer(&size))
    return
}

func (p *Pcre) OPexec(input []byte) ([]int, error) {

    if p.Regex == nil {
        return nil, ErrNotInit
    }

    inputC := (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&input[0]))

    var ovector [3]C.int
    var res []int

    rc := C.pcre_exec((*C.pcre)(unsafe.Pointer(&p.Regex[0])), nil, inputC, C.int(len(input)), 0, 0, &ovector[0], 3)
    if rc < 0 {
        switch rc {
        case C.PCRE_ERROR_NOMATCH:
            return nil, ErrNotmatch
        case C.PCRE_ERROR_BADOPTION:
            return nil, ErrBadoption
        case C.PCRE_ERROR_MATCHLIMIT:
            return nil, ErrMatchLimit
        default:
            return nil, errors.New("Error executing regex : " + strconv.Itoa(int(rc)))
        }
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Sindex : %d, Lindex : %d\n", ovector[0], ovector[1])
    res = []int{int(ovector[0]), int(ovector[1])}

    return res, nil

}
```

i used "pcre_study" for set match limit, and set it into 10000000, but it still return -8